Installing ubuntu failed after selecting "try and install ubuntu"
I am trying to install ubuntu on my newly built PC but so far I always stuck at the booting phase.
here is what I have done

Install windows
free some space (500GiB) for ubuntu
download ubuntu desktop here https://ubuntu.com/desktop
use rufus to create a bootable usb drive
disable secure boot and fastboot
restart my pc and use f12 to choose boot from the usb drive
I saw the screen for selecting different booting option
e.g. try and install ubuntu, graphic safe mode etc
Then after select try and install ubuntu I saw this screen stuck screen
then the process just hangs there for ever

few thing I tried,

connecting monitor to motherboard video output same thing
tried the graphics safe mode, same thing
my build
gigabyte x870 motherboard
9800x3d
gigabyte 4060 gpu

let me know if you need more information . I suspect the boot setting in the bios maybe a bit fishy, but not sure where it went wrong.


Don't disable Secure Boot. 2. In Windows, disable Fast Startup, as well as Fast Boot in BIOS. 3. Be sure Windows is completely stopped, e.g., shutdown /s /f /t 00.

